# Pressure of sudden onset blackout in Tropical Island Capital

Tags: internal-consistency, politics, earth-like, government, cities

So in a world that is just like ours,  there is an island in the Tropics,  just a little North of the Equator,  to all sides surrounded by minimum 200 km of Indian Ocean.

There is one island, it is the most densely populated space on Earth. 
116.000 people live in 2,5 sqm area,  which is filled with Multistorey buildings to house all those people and other buildings of all sorts,  since it is the capital and seat of Government of Maldives.

The country is reliant on Diesel Imports,  which it uses as fuel in the Islands power plant,  to supply electricity everywhere in the island,  and to power the 2 desalination plants that provide the sweet water supply for the population of the island city.

Since every member of population needs minimum 20 liters of clean water,  this adds to Minimum required 2 Million Liters of water per day, just to support this one island.

In the world that I'd been meaning to build,  there is now a sudden catastrophy occurring.

The Planets magnetic poles are shifting,  just as at the same time the sun belched forth a cosmic flare of plasma,  with the increased radiation reaching earth and,  there being no protection magnetic shield as the magnetic field has destabilised due to the switch and has yet to realign itself, penetrates and ionises the upper layers of the atmosphere.

The Electromagnetic Pulse knocks out all satellite communication,  as the satellites internal components receive a damaging voltage and overload due to the radiation. 
Hardened military satellites face a losing battle against myriads of fragments from colliding satellites.

Meanwhile on the surface of the planet,  all Metall exposed to the radiation from Space is getting electrically charged. Metal railings might give of a spark or shock when touched or get warm.

Sensible electronics like computers,  smartphones and perhaps even CB broadcast systems are damaged beyond repair.

Sophisticated vehicle controls suffer the same fate,  with electronic and computational components,  along with any sophisticated sensor,  are damaged and the motorbikes and lorries so commonly used come to a stop.

The island is now in a situation where it is very green (emitting no greenhouse emissions due to energy consumption) but at the same time is basically pushed back into medieval circumstances.

So I am stuck now as in regards to how long it would take for the population to be reduced to what the island can support.

It's easy to imagine for example the grim scenes of demonstrating,  enraged fathers of children with dried up lips,  and the scene dissolving as tear gas is used to disperse the crowds.

However I fail to be able to draft a probable time table for the unravelling of events. 
If x was the day production of water stopped, the stores would lose a lot of stock on the market but run dry within 2-3 days.

People will try to drink ground water,  but it is salty and full of pathogens.

Where will population numbers be 7, 10, 14, 21, 24, 28 days after the water supply runs dry?

(Note: And yes I try to stay on Topic, however the world as a whole would face challenges as well. In no other place on the planet would the situation however be so dire and deteriorate as quickly as there. 
Starting to describe events in chronological order there would help in having a framework for other parts of that world.)

Comment: Welcome to the site. I suggest reading the [tour] and perusing the [help] to get more familiar with the site. As it stands, your question is somewhat confusing to me. What power supply are you mentioning? How did it get plugged off, why can't they start again? Do they need electric source for fresh water? Etc. But importantly, I fear your question focuses on the scenario. And as interesting as that maybe, it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: Well I shouldn't ask questions I can answer for my own. The idea of forming a world (like ours now) and then applying pole shift,  solar storm would differ from place to place. However this scenario was supposed to show harshness where it would most quickly show up,  on an outpost depending on supply.

Comment: If this is really just about the water issue, you might consider deleting all of the backstory unrelated to the question, and instead say that all electronics have been fried with no warning, and no explanation. That should help your question make more sense.

Comment: Standard humans can survive 3-5 days without water, with recorded cases going up to a week. They'd need to find water fast, my guess would be getting the water from the air through condensation, though I have no idea how much water you would be getting. On a side note, Maldives are threatened IRL with extinction by rising sea levels, so they'll get their water eventually.

Comment: Your water use figures are for normal usage including dishwashing, showers, ect. For survival reduce it to 3-4 Liters per day.

Comment: My grandfather stated that during WWII in the North African desert their water ration was 1 liter per day for all uses - and they were expected to shave every day.  I do not know whether they had access to water other than their water ration

Answer (score 0):

By the end of Day 7, most will be dead. The only survivors will be those who a) have managed to set up solar stills or take charge of a water storage tank, and b) have been able to defend them. Since stills are fragile, most of the first stills were rendered inoperative during the fights to control them. It is entirely up to you as to how many stills have survived, and why. The storage tanks, of course, are quite large as part of the island's water distribution system, but their locations are also easily determined, and will be the source of conflict among the survivors.

After this point, of course, with a stable base of survivors, the next question will be that of starvation. The only source of food will be fish caught in the surrounding sea. Only a few old boats with diesel engines and obsolete ignition systems, or sailboats, will be operating, so that source is limited.